# Upgrade only a single chart \ application

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a chart named all-services and normally, I would do this which deploys all the services (as given in the requirements) :

```
helm upgrade prod-allservics all-services/.
```

This would deploy, the below services:

```
backup-service
counter-service
bridge-service
```

But now I just need to deploy the service counter-service and not touch the others. Is it possible and if so, how ? I understand that grouping does mean it needs to be deployed together, but there might be scenarios where you do not want to touch other charts.

Answer (score 1):

In your vaule.yaml file you can add variables to enable services e.g. `backupServiceEnabled: true` then in a requirements.yaml file you can add conditions to your services e.g.

`dependencies:
  - name: backup-service
    condition: backupServiceEnabled.enabled`

Comment: (This is highly likely to have the side effect of uninstalling the backup service.  Double-check with `helm template` or `helm upgrade --dry-run` to be sure!)

Answer (score 1):

In general in Kubernetes, if you submit some object that's identical to the object that's already there, nothing happens.  For example, say you have a Deployment named `all-services-bridge-service`, and you submit an identical Deployment with the same name and same contents; the Kubernetes core controllers will look at the new Deployment, see that the existing Pods exactly match what is requested by the Deployment, and do nothing.  When I say "submit" here I mean either `kubectl apply` or the equivalent work done by `helm upgrade`.

So say you have a Helm values file that looks like

```
backup-service:
  tag: 1.2.3
counter-service:
  tag: 1.4.0
bridge-service:
  tag: 3.2.1
```

where the templates copy `.Values.tag` into the Deployments' `image:` settings.  Now, say you have a release of `counter-service` and change

```
counter-service:
  tag: 1.5.0
```

You can safely `helm upgrade` the whole thing.  Yes, it will produce a new deployment spec for the other two services and submit them, but since the image tag (and presumably other details) are the same, there will be no net effect.  Even if there are changes, the resulting rotation of Pods should be pretty routine.

If it's important to you to be able to only upgrade these sub-charts one at a time, you will need to promote them to top-level charts.  (In other contexts I've found a chart-of-charts managing multiple microservices to not work especially well; if A requires Redis and B requires Redis, for example, a combined umbrella chart that installs both A and B will only install one Redis and share it, which you probably don't want.)